# Symfony 2: MemcachePool not found

Tags: php, symfony, memcached

I was upgrading my Symfony 2 project, which works with the lws_memcache Bundle.

Now my I get the following error:

> ClassNotFoundException in LoggingMemcache.php line 4: 
>   Attempted to load class "MemcachePool" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

The File lies in the vendor of the lws_memcache Bundle, so I can't change the code.

My memcached Server is on the version 1.4.14, the bundle itself is the newest verison.

This is what my IDE (PHPStorm 8) shows me when I hover over the Class `\MemcachePool` in the vendor code.

> Multiple definitions exist for class MemcachePool less... (Strg+F1)
>
> Undefined class: Declaration of referenced class is not found in
>   built-in library and project files. Multiple declarations: this
>   version of IDE *will* have problems with completion, member resolution
>   and inheritance analysis for all classes that have multiple
>   definitions in project files (regardless of includes).

Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: This appears to be an incompatibility between the PHP5 implementation of memcache and the HHVM implementation of memcache. PHP5 has a \MemcachePool class which, as far as I can tell, is not documented, but it is what LoggingMemcache extends in the leaseweb memcache bundle. The HHVM implementation of memcache is fundamentally different.

I do not know of any solution but I would like to hear if one exists.

Comment: Sadly I don't know one by now. I rerolled my proiect to the earlier Version an it worked again

Answer (score 2):

LswMemcacheBundle bundle is compatible with memcache 3.0.6 or higher. I was having the same error with php-memcache 2.2.x.

Try upgrading your php-memcache to the new one (3.0.8), but first you need to edit the formula and setup the flags  `brew edit php56-memcache`  :

```
.  20     safe_phpize
.  21 
+  22     ENV['MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.11'
+  23     ENV['CFLAGS'] = '-fgnu89-inline'
+  24     ENV['LDFLAGS'] = '-fgnu89-inline'
+  25     ENV['CXXFLAGS'] = '-fgnu89-inline'
+  26 
.  27     system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}",
.  28                           phpconfig
.  29     system "make"

$ brew uninstall homebrew/php/php56-memcache
$ brew install homebrew/php/php56-memcache --devel
```

Then restart php-fpm + nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config file has a memcache session pool defined.

Try rebooting the server.

I had the same issue when installing LwsMemcache in my symfony project. I received the exact same error on production as the one above, but on my dev box, It was a different error (can't remember what it said), but had to do with php5 and memcache not working together.

restarting the services for nginx and php5-fpm did not work. I had to reboot and it works fine.

Comment: I did this, but without success. I rerolled the upgrade to the previous one, then my project worked again. But I still have no solution to this problem.